# SQL Server : trying to make a check statement, but having a problem when I try in practise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a function that checks how many items are in storage:

```sql
alter function dbo.preveriZalogo(@St int,@ID int)
returns int
as 
begin
    declare @Kol int;
    select @Kol=sum(Kolicina) from Stanje
    where IzdelekID=@ID
    return (@Kol+@St);
end;
GO
```

It checks in view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW Stanje 
AS
select
    Skladisce.Naziv as Skladisce,
    UvozIzvoz.IzdelekID,
    Izdelek.Naziv as Pijaca,
    sum(UvozIzvoz.Kolicina) as Kolicina
from UvozIzvoz
inner join SkladisceDelavec
    on SkladisceDelavec.ID = UvozIzvoz.SkladisceDelavecID
inner join Skladisce
    on Skladisce.ID = SkladisceDelavec.SkladisceID
inner join Izdelek
    on Izdelek.ID = UvozIzvoz.IzdelekID
group by
    Skladisce.Naziv,
    IzdelekID,
    Izdelek.Naziv;
```

Then I created a `CHECK` constraint:

```sql
alter table UvozIzvoz
add constraint PreveriAliJeNaZalogi
check (dbo.preveriZalogo(Kolicina,IzdelekID)>=0);
```

When I ran:

```
select * from Stanje;
```

I get the following result:

| Skladisce | IzdelekID | Izdelek | kolicina |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Skladišče 1 | 1 | Coca Cola 1.5L | 12 |
| Skladišče 1 | 2 | Coca Cola 0.33L | 24 |
| Skladišče 1 | 3 | Ledeni čaj breskev Sola 0.33L | 24 |
| Skladišče 1 | 4 | Red bull 0.25L | 24 |
| Skladišče 1 | 6 | Vino Sauvignonasse Gor.Brda 20L | 3 |
| Skladišče 1 | 7 | Jagermeister 1L | 2 |
| Skladišče 1 | 8 | Whisky Jack Daniels old No.7 1L | 4 |
| Skladišče 1 | 10 | Pivo Laško Zlatorog Svetlo 0.5 | 16 |
| Skladišče 1 | 11 | Pivo Union 6*0.5 | 4 |

and if try to run a insert statement that will deduct 12 from Coca Cola 1,5L supply, the check statement interferes.
The error:

"The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "PreveriAliJeNaZalogi". The conflict occurred in database "SkladisceTD", table "dbo.UvozIzvoz"."

the select statement:

```
insert into UvozIzvoz(Kolicina,IzdelekID,SkladisceDelavecID)
values(-12,1,1);
```

Comment: Your function never initializes `@qua`.  And it doesn't define `@kol`.

Comment: Your function logic also illustrates a general flaw in your approach to coding. Your function sums but has a group by clause. In theory, it can produce multiple rows. In such cases, the engine will assign a value to your variable but there is no guarantee of which row will be used for that assignment. Here you don't need a group by clause because you filter for a specific value of ItemID which you also include in the group by clause. Just remove the group by clause as it is logical nonsense (after correcting for other problems).

Comment: _It checks in view:_ No it does not. Your view does not reference the table StorageDisplay nor does it include the columns Quantity and ItemID from UvozIzvoz.

Comment: My problem was that I tried to translate variable names into english and with that I only made more mistakes, now I've published my original code.

Comment: Look again - your function references table Stanje but your view references tables UvozIzvoz, SkladisceDelavec, Skladisce, and Izdelek. Quite simply, there is no logical or obvious relationship between the view and your function so the statement "It checks in view" does not make sense. The previous comments are still accurate. If you want help, I suggest you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Whitespace doesn't cost. What does `I try to insert -15, so it will deduct from current supply. When I try inserting -1, it goes through multiple times until it's only "1" item in storage` mean, I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem. I didn't know that when you make a insert with a check statement, that it will first insert into the table and then check if that is correct.